# Making a loading page (waiting view) for iPhone apps and games

Tags: iphone

I have seen quite number of games in Iphone. I see there is loading page (waiting view) when the scenes switch. Like scene A goes to scene B, it takes time to load right? but to let the user know so the developer put the waiting view. I am not sure how to do it. I am still new with that, just built one game, and there are still problems, I think that will help me. So anyone knows please share with me your knowledge.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create some viewController class to represent your waiting screen logic, then just use `presentModalViewController:animated:` method to show it. when you don't need it, just call `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIActivityIndicatorView control.
See following 
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html